# Pandas Group by sum of all the values of the group and another column as comma separated

Tags: python, aggregate, pandas-groupby

I want to group by one column (tag) and sum up the corresponding quantites (qty). The related reference no. column should be separated by commas

```
import pandas as pd

tag = ['PO_001045M100960','PO_001045M100960','PO_001045MSP2526','PO_001045M870191', 'PO_001045M870191', 'PO_001045M870191']
reference= ['PA_000003', 'PA_000005', 'PA_000001', 'PA_000002', 'PA_000004', 'PA_000009']
qty=[4,2,2,1,1,1]

df = pd.DataFrame({'tag' : tag, 'reference':reference, 'qty':qty})

      tag           reference   qty
PO_001045M100960    PA_000003   4
PO_001045M100960    PA_000005   2
PO_001045MSP2526    PA_000001   2
PO_001045M870191    PA_000002   1
PO_001045M870191    PA_000004   1
PO_001045M870191    PA_000009   1
```

If I use df.groupby('tag')['qty'].sum().reset_index(), I am getting the following result.

```
         tag           qty
ASL_PO_000001045M100960 6
ASL_PO_000001045M870191 3
ASL_PO_000001045MSP2526 2
```

I need an additional column where the reference no. are added under the respective tags like,

```
         tag           qty     refrence
ASL_PO_000001045M100960 6      PA_000003, PA_000005
ASL_PO_000001045M870191 3      PA_000002, PA_000004, PA_000009
ASL_PO_000001045MSP2526 2      PA_000001
```

How can I achieve this?

Thanks.

Comment: What is your input data's reference has PA as prefix and expected output has TNIPL?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `pandas.DataFrame.groupby.agg`:

```
df.groupby('tag').agg({'qty': 'sum', 'reference': ', '.join})
```

Output:

```
                                        reference  qty
tag                                                   
PO_001045M100960             PA_000003, PA_000005    6
PO_001045M870191  PA_000002, PA_000004, PA_000009    3
PO_001045MSP2526                        PA_000001    2
```

Note: if `reference` column is numeric, `', '.join` will not work. In such case, use `lambda x: ', '.join(str(i) for i in x)`